# Chart.js shaded regions

Tags: javascript, charts, html5-canvas, chart.js

Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) can fill the color below line charts using the "fillColor" attribute (filling the region between the line chart itself and the x-axis).

What I'd like to know is whether Chart.js can be configured to create shaded regions such as the one shown below:

http://peltiertech.com/Excel/pix5/HorizBands09.png

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the striping you need is already in the API. But you could draw the striping after the chart has been drawn by setting `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over'` and using the data points to apply the stripes with `context.fillRect`. Note: "destination over" compositing will cause your stripes to be drawn *under existing content*. Be sure you set compositing back to its default after you're done: `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'`.

Answer (score 9):

## Shaded Regions for Line Charts

You can extend the chart to do this.

---

**Preview**

[image]

or

[image]

---

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function (data) {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        var ranges = [
            {
                start: 100,
                end: 75,
                color: 'rgba(250,0,0,0.5)'
            },
            {
                start: 75,
                end: 50,
                color: 'rgba(0,250,0,0.5)'
            },
            {
                start: 50,
                end: 25,
                color: 'rgba(0,0,250,0.5)'
            },
            {
                start: 25,
                end: 0,
                color: 'rgba(250,250,0,0.5)'
            }
        ];

        var scale = this.scale;
        var rangesStart = scale.calculateY(ranges[0].start);
        var rangesEnd = scale.calculateY(ranges[ranges.length - 1].end);
        var gradient = this.chart.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, rangesStart, 0, rangesEnd);

        ranges.forEach(function (range) {
            gradient.addColorStop((scale.calculateY(range.start) - rangesStart) / (rangesEnd - rangesStart), range.color);
            gradient.addColorStop((scale.calculateY(range.end) - rangesStart) / (rangesEnd - rangesStart), range.color);
        })

        this.datasets[0].fillColor = gradient;
    }
});
```

and then

```
...
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

If you want to shade the whole background use

```
var originalDraw = scale.draw;
scale.draw = function() {
    originalDraw.apply(this, arguments);

  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(scale.calculateX(0), scale.startPoint, scale.width, scale.endPoint - scale.startPoint);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

instead of `this.datasets[0].fillColor = gradient;`

---

Fiddle (below line) - http://jsfiddle.net/61vg048r/

Fiddle (whole background) - http://jsfiddle.net/u4Lk7xns/

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how would I extend the colour strips to cover the whole graph (as in the link shown in the original post), rather than simply stop when the strip "hits" the line chart. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Thanks .. looking solution in angular 2