# How to implement stripped background with ng2-charts?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-charts

How can I implement shaded regions (stripped background) on charts using ng2-charts similar to chartjs library implementation of below? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860311/chart-js-shaded-regions

[image]

I have tried to shade regions of datasets check below image, but instead i want the background to be drawn as rectangular different regions with different colors. What i am facing right now is two issues

1. I cannot figure-out where `scale` attribute with functions like `scale.calculateY` & `scale.draw` function within ng2-charts
2. Even with the hardcoded values if i try to draw the rectangle it seems below two line of codes doesnt actually draw the rectangle background.

   `this.chart.ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    this.chart.ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);`

[image]

Comment: Check this answer: [stackoverflow chart js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372827/chart-js-color-specific-parts-of-the-background-in-a-line-chart)