# Possible implementation of shaded regions in ng2-charts

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-charts

How to implement shaded regions using [ng2-charts](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) library just the same way like chartjs library implementation from below stack-overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860311/chart-js-shaded-regions)

Image[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far?